# Losing qualifiers during template argument deduction

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates

Since I am using C++11, I have written my own `make_unique` function which takes a variadic template parameter pack and forwards it to the `std::unique_ptr` constructor. This works fine for simple data types. However, the objects I am trying to construct accept other type objects by const reference. On passing const references however, I am getting "Conversions loses qualifiers" i.e.

```
struct A {};
struct B { B(const A& ob) { ... } };

A ob;
auto ptr = make_unique<B>(ob); // error here

// Definition of make_unique below:

template <typename T, typename... Args>
std::unique_ptr<T> make_unique(Args&&... args)
{ 
    return std::unique_ptr<T>{ new T{std::forward<Args>(args)...} } ;
}
```

The error I am facing is

```
Conversions loses qualifiers, cannot convert argument 1 from 'const A' to 'A &'.
```

How do I resolve the error? From what I can understand, the template type deduction is not what I am expecting it to be.

Compiler: MSVC 2015, Update 3

Comment: This compiles just fine with `g++-8` and `clang`.

Comment: Try using normal parentheses instead of brace initialization for T: `new T(std::forward<Args>(args)...)`.

Comment: Indeed, the snippet works even in g++4.8 and up, and also in clang. I will have to look if something changed in class 'A' constructors (may be they accept non-const references instead) after latest checkout.

Comment: Also seems to be working with MSCV 2015U3: https://godbolt.org/g/HXZH5D

Answer (score 3):

This is most likely a compiler bug. It works fine with clang, g++, and also with current versions of MSVC 2017 as well as 2015. So I guess updating your Visual Studio should fix the issue.

[working test example here](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'%23include+%3Cutility%3E%0A%23include+%3Cmemory%3E%0A%0Astruct+A+%7B%7D%3B%0Astruct+B+%7B+B(const+A%26+ob)+%7B+%7D+%7D%3B%0A%0A//+Definition+of+make_unique+below:%0A%0Atemplate+%3Ctypename+T,+typename...+Args%3E%0Astd::unique_ptr%3CT%3E+make_unique(Args%26%26...+args)%0A%7B%0A%09return+std::unique_ptr%3CT%3E%7B+new+T%7B+std::forward%3CArgs%3E(args)...+%7D+%7D%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aint+main()%0A%7B%0A%09A+ob%3B%0A%09auto+ptr+%3D+make_unique%3CB%3E(ob)%3B+//+error+here%0A%7D%0A'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:55.359173878387125,l:'4',m:71.37724550898203,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1,wrap:'1'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%231+with+x86-64+clang+6.0.0',t:'0')),header:(),l:'4',m:28.622754491017965,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),k:59.00783289817232,l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang600,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',trim:'0'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+clang+6.0.0+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:40.99216710182768,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4)

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, struct 'B' from the above code indeed changed it's constructor parameter to accept a non-const reference, but the documentation had no corresponding updates. Thank you everyone for the help!